# Trying to use AWS' SelectObjectContent but getting error code: NotImplemented

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I am running the following code to get the number of records in a parquet file placed inside an S3 bucket.

```
    import boto3
    import os

    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    sql_stmt    = """SELECT count(*) FROM s3object s"""   
    
    req_fact =s3.select_object_content( 
        Bucket  = 'test_hadoop', 
        Key     = 'counter_db.cm_workload_volume_sec.dt=2023-01-23.cm_workload_volume_sec+2+000000347262.parquet', 
        ExpressionType  = 'SQL', 
        Expression      = sql_stmt, 
        InputSerialization={'Parquet':{}}, 
        OutputSerialization = {'JSON': {}})
    
    for event in req_fact['Payload']:
        if 'Records' in event:
            print(event['Records']['Payload'].decode('utf-8'))
        elif 'Stats' in event:
            print(event['Stats'])
```

However I get this error: botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (XNotImplemented) when calling the SelectObjectContent operation: This node does not support SelectObjectContent.

What is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code against a known good (uncompressed) parquet file with no errors.

```
resp = s3.select_object_content(
    Bucket='my-test-bucket',
    Key='counter_db.cm_workload_volume_sec.dt=2023-01-23.cm_workload_volume_sec+2+000000347262.parquet',
    ExpressionType='SQL',
    Expression="SELECT count(*) FROM s3object s",
    InputSerialization={'Parquet': {}},
    OutputSerialization={'JSON': {}},
)

Output:
{"_1":4}
```

In the AWS console you can navigate to the S3 bucket and find the file, highlight it and choose to run S3 select there (Actions > Query with S3 Select).  That will allow you to validate that the file can be queried with S3 select (which I think is your issue here)

Note the following:  Amazon S3 Select does not support whole-object compression for Apache Parquet objects.